# Set ui-select value using ID from an array of objects

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

Well I have the array of objects in this format

```
$scope.itemArray = [
        {id: 1, name: 'first'},
        {id: 2, name: 'second'},
        {id: 3, name: 'third'},
        {id: 4, name: 'fourth'},
        {id: 5, name: 'fifth'},
    ];

$scope.selectedItem = $scope.itemArray[0];//this works fine
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.itemArray[0].id;//this doesn't works
```

and this is the html part:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in itemArray | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

What I am trying to do is set the ui-select value using the `id` column, but I am unable to do so. I am sure that I am wrong somewhere and also very much new to this plugin. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your ng-repeat with the following:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.id as item in itemArray | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind="item.name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/k0PR01wnbOUdFnOrvHb6?p=preview)**

You can find more information about this plugin in this git page. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices